# troubles publishing closedxml to azure app service

Tags: closedxml

When I try to publish my webAPI to azure I get this error
[image: error]

It says something about degradation of the package. Reference it directly from the project but I don't know what is needed

Any idea Please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing the package directly in the project
[image: error]

thanks